# Priorizar evento onclick

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma tabela que possui um evento ao clicar na tr e td. Preciso colocar um campo texto dentro da td com um evento ao clicar também. Quando faço isso os eventos da tr e td são priorizados e o evento do campo texto não funciona.
Como faço para forçar o evento onclick do campo texto?

Obrigado

Comment: Cara coloca o seu código ai, html/js sem eles fica difícil te responder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca isso no campo de texto pra evitar propagação dos eventos dos parentes. Mais informações [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
document.querySelector('.seuInput').addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: Mas e se a `tr` tiver outros elementos filhos que deveriam ser clicáveis? É mais fácil tratar esse problema colocando um `stopPropagation` no campo de texto.

Comment: Realmente, concordo com você, alterei a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente